# Erro na lógica para substituir todas as frases dentro de um arquivo x usando Bash Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, sh

Como posso substituir todas as frases iguais dentro de um arquivo, usando Bash Shell Script, ao receber o valor a ser substituído de uma variável?

1 - Como eu gostaria - **porém não funciona**.:

```
 txtSalt="frase-que-sera-substituida"

    perl -i -pe'
    BEGIN {
        @chars = ("a" .. "z", "A" .. "Z", 0 .. 9);
        push @chars, split //, "!@#$%^&*()-_ []{}<>~\`+=,.;:/?|";
        sub salt { join "", map $chars[ rand @chars ], 1 .. 64 }
    }
    s/$txtSalt/salt()/ge
    ' meuarquivo.php
```

2 - **Como funciona** - com a frase aplicada diretamente.:

```
    perl -i -pe'
    BEGIN {
        @chars = ("a" .. "z", "A" .. "Z", 0 .. 9);
        push @chars, split //, "!@#$%^&*()-_ []{}<>~\`+=,.;:/?|";
        sub salt { join "", map $chars[ rand @chars ], 1 .. 64 }
    }
    s/frase-que-sera-substituida/salt()/ge
    ' meuarquivo.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de aspas simples (') tudo é interpretado literalmente. Isto é, você precisa fechar as aspas simples, colocar algo entre aspas duplas ("), e re-abrir as aspas simples.

```
'codigoAntes'"$variavel"'codigoDepois'
```

No seu caso, ficaria:

```
[...]
s/'"$txtSalt"'/salt()/ge
[...]
```

Tenha em mente que concatenar variáveis para formar um comando de Bash não é boa prática, pois você fica vulnerável de maneira similar a uma [SQL Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).
Claro, em um script pequeno como o seu em que a variável está definida de forma literal no topo acredito não ter problema.

Para uma leitura mais aprofundada, veja [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802438/10746978) (em inglês).